# How is it possible, that a new user asks the same question twice within a minute?

Tags: bug, new-users, first-questions

The screenshot says it all

[image]

I believe this must be a bug, or something weird going on.

Comment: Clarification: it's not within a minute. It's within a second (18:02:59Z and 18:03:00Z).

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with software engineering or have ever written code but there is a thing called "race condition" and/or "replay detection". That is probably at play here. Hard to solve. Yes bug, by design when it comes to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrewT. A second is much like an aeon for a server ;-)

Comment: @rene you know enough of me to realize that I'm well aware of that. But bug is bug

Comment: I know enough devs that think a "race condition" is about Max Verstappen ... ;)

Comment: Not really sure, but the question ID # is one apart between them (72509900 and 72509901). I custom-flagged a few hours ago asking for them to be merged, but yeah, that shouldn't really happen (in theory).

Comment: This needs the thread-safety car out.

Comment: A second is not that long, especially if the distance between both was less than a second. In general a good response time on the internet is 40ms, but that isn't for a commit. Lookup is much slower, and since Stack Overflow takes advantage of using non locking reads, it is highly probable that the system will never recognize this discrepancy, no matter how close it looks. Even in the scenario where it looks in memory or in cache you could have overlapping application pools which would invalidate the search. The only time this would make sense to look would be if the commit was retried.